# Possible delays in detecting file system changes?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Given: The following C# code snippet in a multi-platform .NET 6 application:

```
using (File.Create("MyFile")) { }
File.Exists("MyFile");
```

Assuming that no other thread or application accesses file "MyFile", is it possible that the file system change caused by File.Create might not occur fast enough to be detected by the immediate File.Exists?

Comment: This isn't detecting changes at all. `File.Create` actually created a file and returned an open stream to that file that was ignored.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Is there a different problem you think is cause by delays ?

Comment: You can't get a warranty in a world polluted with anti-malware.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)...

Comment: Your own code is trying to access the same file twice - first it opens a stream over it with `File.Create` then it tries to access it again with `File.Exists`. As far as the file system is concerned these are two separate file operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible that the file system change caused by File.Create might not occur fast enough to be detected by the immediate File.Exists?

That's not the issue. `File.Create()` returns an opened stream ready-to-use, so the file *must* be available by the time the next statement executes.

Instead, the problem is **`File.Exists()` is bad**, and *you should not use it.*

Specifically for this situation, note this excerpt from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-7.0):

> The Exists method returns false if ***any error*** occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists.

<sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup>

It's not well spelled out, but "any error" can include things like having a file opened and locked, which is part of calling `File.Create()` (it returns an open stream with the default [sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=net-7.0), which is *None*). There are a number of other situations with the file system that can cause this as well, especially relating to network shares, mapped drives, and the like, as well as esoteric or advanced NTFS features.

We also have a `using` block telling the program to immediately dispose the file handle, which would handle the most common among these issues. However, this only releases from the program to the OS, which in turn has it's own buffering. So the handle does remain open for at least a short time. In certain (rare) pathologic cases the handle could even be held until the computer restarts.

In nearly every situation you should instead just try to open (or otherwise act on) a file when you need it. Don't test for success, but rather *build good exception handlers* to deal with any exceptions you encounter for file operations as they occur. This improves performance and better addresses volatility issues with the file system.

Comment: Without knowing what the actual problem (and question) is, I can think of file system differences in snapshot/temp file behavior that could hide a file created in one operation from another one. In Transactional NTFS, a file created in a transaction won't be visible outside it. Linux file systems with snapshot support go much farther than that

Comment: I wasn't aware that this forum was only for questions related to problems the OP was actually encountering.  The only problem I was having was not knowing the answer to the hypothetical question I asked.  I thought the question was fairly straightforward and I appreciate that Joel provided some relevant information.